# Removing matching items from a list?

Tags: python

Basically, I'm trying to find out how to remove matching items from a list. But there doesn't seem to be any information on how to go about doing this specific function.

For example, what I want is:

let's say there is a list:

```
pHands[0] = ['ad', 'ac', 'as', 'ah', '7d', '8s', '9d', 'td', 'js', 'jd']
```

So up there, my list, which is named `pHands[0]` has ten items in it.

I'm trying to make a function where a search is initiated into the list and any matching items with a first matching number/letter reaching four are removed.

So in the end, `ad, ac, as, ah` (the four a's) will all be deleted/removed from the list. I need the list to automatically detect if there are four matching first letter/numbers in the items in the list.

The remaining list will be:

```
pHands[0] = ['7d', '8s', '9d', 'td', 'js', 'jd']
```

If it helps, the two letters/numbers in each item are strung together by the following function:

```
for suite in range(4):
    for rank in range(13):
        deck.append(rankList[rank]+suitList[suite])
```

So they can be directly accessed using:
card[0] for the first letter/number
card[1] for the second

This function will be used for other lists too so it can't specifically target "a" and needs to auto search for four matching first letters.

Comment: question has been switched, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: don't "switch" a question with answers, write a new question instead.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to iterate over that player's cards:

```
if any(card[1] == target_card for card in pHands[target_player]):
```

Or pick a better data structure for the cards, like a named tuple.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I also have another question if that would be alright with you.

Comment: I've written the following for deleting the card out of the target player, and then adding it to the human players hand. But I can't seem to figure out whats wrong with it.

Comment: if any(card[1] == target_card for card in pHands[target_player]):
    transfer_cards = card[1] == target_card in pHands[target_player]
    del card[1] == target_card in pHands[target_player]
    if any(card[1] == target_card for card in pHands[0]):
        pHands[0].extend(transfer_cards)

Comment: since the code doesn't work here, I just added it to the bottom of my code in opening post.

Comment: If you have another question, make another post.